# Is there a way to have a single Metadata Navigation which work on multiple documents libraries which share the same site columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, filter, managed-metadata, metadata-navigation

I am working on an online modern team site collection. and we have 5 documents libraries, where these document libraries share the same 3 managed metadata site columns. Now for each document library, I have defined the following inside its Metadata Navigation settings:-

[image]

I am able to filter the documents based on the managed metadata site columns. But since our 5 document libraries share the same managed metadata site columns, can I create a general Metadata Navigation which will work on all the document libraries, so I can filter all these document libraries at once?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve something similar like this. Follow below steps:

1. **Create Site Columns** and add the same site column to all your document libraries (I guess you already did this). Make sure **Managed property** is created for your site column from URL: `siteUrl/_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=sitecol`
2. Create a **Result Source** which will fetch the documents from multiple document libraries. You can set its by defining multiple `Path` like below:

   [Working with Result Sources to limit search results](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx)

```
   {searchTerms} path:"https://siteURL.com/DocumentLibrary1/*" path:"https://siteURL/DocumentLibrary2/*" path:"https://siteURL/DocumentLibrary3/*"
```

3. Then you can add your site column as a **Refiner** to the Search results page in SharePoint like given below:

   [How to add refiners to your search results page in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page)
4. Then you can add the **Search Results** web part to your SharePoint page and configure it with newly created **Result Source**.
5. Additionally you can also connect the **Search Results** webpart with **Search Box** webpart.

   [How to configure the Search Results Web Part to use a new result source in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-configure-the-search-results-web-part-to-use-a-new-result-source)

**Update**:

**How to use Managed Metadata column as refiners:**

Check below articles on how to use managed metadata(term sets) as refiners in Search:

1. [Refiners for Managed Metadata Columns in SharePoint Online](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aatishblogs/2014/02/02/refiners-for-managed-metadata-columns-in-sharepoint-online/).
2. [Creating Custom Search Refiners in Office 365 using Term Sets](https://nikcharlebois.com/creating-custom-search-refiners-in-office-365-using-term-sets/).

Comment: ok thanks for this, but when i define Metadata Navigation on the list, the filters will be connected to the term sets, while using the search web parts appraoch the user will have to type-in the filter values, rather than selecting the related terms... so that why i was asking if we can have the same user experience for the Metadata navigation but to filter multiple document libraries..

Comment: No, user will not have to search for values in search box. Search box is optional... You can add refiners like the metadata navigation only. So, this is the only option you can filter the documents from multiple libraries. Using metadata navigation and fetching documents from multiple libraries is not possible.

Comment: ok i got your point, but can i link the refiner with the term sets' terms? or i have to manually manage the refiners?

Comment: Check update section in answer to check how to create refiners using managed metadata.

Comment: wonderful your update is exactly what i am looking for!  but one last question, if i follow this appraoch then i have to stay on classic UI ? is this correct? as i do not think the modern search will allow us to define our custom refiners as in the classic search ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You need to use classic UI for this.

Comment: The issue is that i am working on modern communication site  and on a modern team site, and i am unable to create classic page, all the pages i can create will be modern pages, so i am not sure if i can add a classic refiner web part into modern teams or modern communication sites? second question, in one of the links you provided they mentioned the following `add a search refinement panel in the search results page` but the search page (`osssearchresults.aspx`) can not be edited.. so i am a bit confused,,

Comment: In order to use classic page on your communication site, try adding **Web Part page** Content type on **Site Pages** library. And `add a search refinement panel in the search results` means you need to create one classic page where you will add **Search Results** web part and you need to edit that page in order to add refinement panel. You don't have to edit the `osssearchresults.aspx` page.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarifications, will try your appraoch and let you know the results.. sorry i do not have enough reputation to rate your reply and you useful comments.. thanks

Comment: Sure, try it and let me know if this works for you or if you face any issues.